# Can file identifier specify a string as output in Matlab fprintf?

Tags: matlab

The title is somewhat misleading but it captures what I'm trying to do.

Matlab provides the standard `fprintf` function for output to either standard output (the screen) or a file. This is nice because I can write a routine that takes as input an optional filename (using `varargin`) so that when when a filename is passed the routine outputs to the file whereas when it is absent it outputs to screen.

What I wonder is if there is a way of specifying output to a string, such as with the `sprintf` function, but with `fprintf`, so that I can reuse the same routine and have it return the output as a string to the calling function, without need to replace all of the `fprintf` calls with `sprintf`. I know that I can in principle either duplicate all `fprintf` lines with `sprintf` and add conditional statements, or read the contents of a scratch output file into a string in the main calling function, but is there a way to circumvent that to minimize changing existing code?

Update:  I am seeking something similar to redirection in a *nix shell, but that is not quite the right analogy. Basically write to a buffer and return the pointer to a string would be the closest analog. So in a call to

```
function s = do_something(fid);
...
fprintf(fid,fmt,vars)
...
```

if fid pointed to a string variable or buffer that could be read by the calling routine that would solve the problem. It might be possible at a lower level with java?

Comment: You are saying that you have code `fprintf(fid,...)` and you'd like to tweak `fid` so that the function call returns a string. But your code is not taking the output argument of the function call, so where should the string go?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, that is the rub. In a comment to an answer I explain that I am seeking something similar to redirection in a *nix shell, but that is not quite the right analogy. Basically write to a buffer and return the pointer to a string would be the closest analog. So if fid pointed to a string variable that would solve the problem. It might be possible at a lower level calling a java routine?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a function like `my_fprintf` below and call that from your code.

```
function my_fprintf(fid, fmt, s)
% Writes sprintf(fmt, s) to the screen if fid == 0 or file fid otherwise

if fid == 0
    fprintf(fmt, s);
else
    fprintf(fid, fmt, s);
end
```

Comment: Ok, that is a reasonable alternative I suppose although you missed one of the points, which is being able to switch between the behavior of ´s=sprintf(...´ and plain ´fprintf´ by passing say the value of fid (if fid=1 fprintf writes to the screen making your code redundant)

Comment: I'll be honest, I think my question was not well thought out now that I think about it :-\ I don't think I can get the behavior I want in some obvious simple way. Basically I am looking for behaviour like Unix redirection. Thanks for your effort in any case. Maybe I'll have to use a function.